# Intersecting ellipses recognition in image C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv, bioinformatics, ellipse

For a research project, I have to find the ellipses in a fossil image.
For each fossil image, I also have a CSV file containing the contour of the fossil, in cartesian coordinates.

I need help in determining the starting and ending points of each ellipses that are present in the fossil, so that I can apply a ellipse-fitting algorithm on them.

I started to look at the possibility of studying the variations in the different slopes of the contour.
It somehow worked, until the point where I tried on fossils that have very low curve variations. As you can see on the image below (click the link), the pink points are where the variation of the slopes of the contours are the highest. However, it doesn't work for the bottom ellipse.

[image: fossil image]

So I need a new approach on that. Do you have any hints or ideas where I can look at ?

Comment: You'll probably get better answers on http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you provide an example of the csv file you are analyzing please?

Comment: Here is an example CSV file : [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nhlrhf60lah20we/MD04_2861K%200104_T)